# how to monitor coffee-resque workers, with resque-web

Tags: resque

I created some workers with coffee-resque and was trying to view workers using the ruby version of resque-web and only saw intermittent workers flash in and out.

I noticed that coffee-resque untracks workers while paused.  Is that the intended behavior?  This made it so that resque web only listed flashing intermittent workers and they always had a status of waiting when they did appear, even though that was when they were processing.

Am I doing it wrong or is there a suggested way of monitoring the worker queues?

Also, is there a way to clean up the inactive orphaned worker keys in redis if the worker process failed and didn't do a graceful untrack on exit?

Answer (score 0):

I recently provided a pull request that fixed this issue.  It has been accepted into coffee-resque and a new version was released.

https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque/issues/17

This fix was released as 0.1.6.